# Attaching Existing Oracle Home to fresh Windows Install

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, windows-server

I have a client who recently was forced to reformat and reinstall Windows Server 2008 R2. Their ORACLE_HOME (Oracle 11g) and all of the data was located on a D: drive that was not reformatted. Can I associate this pre-existing ORACLE_HOME with Windows, or do I need to reinstall?

I'm thinking that all I should need to do is add the missing registry entries, recreate the listener, and use oradim to recreate the system service. If this would work, am I missing anything?

Comment: I went ahead and reinstalled, but I'd still like to know for future reference since this could save a tremendous amount of time if it can be done.